# How to get a list of browser cookies using PHP?

Tags: php

From my understanding `$_COOKIE` gives me all the cookies in a user's browser.

But when I do

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

I get the following:

```
Array
    (
        [wp-settings-1] => m8=o&m2=o&m5=o&m4=o&m3=o&m1=o&m7=o&m0=o
        [wp-settings-time-1] => 1329859655
        [PHPSESSID] => ST88bLB7PE5S9BbY5oXxLgDIcas
    )
```

This list does not match the list I see in the browser. For example, PHPSESSID is not in the list of cookies in my browser. Am I accessing the wrong variable?

Thanks.

Comment: in PHP you can only see cookie that placed on your current running script domain and path or ancestor domain/path.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `PHPSESSID` is the session cookie added by PHP.

Comment: think of the security implications if site A could see cookies set by  site B

Comment: @PeeHaa how can I mark your comment as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned `$_COOKIE` only gives you cookies for the current domain/path. You cannot see all cookies in a browser. You can see how this works if you ever sniff/view HTTP packets. When you make an HTTP request, the browser sends cookies to the server. [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) has some excellent examples of what that HTTP traffic looks like.